# adding numbers in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database that has the column balance. This table is used for storing data about a user's account balance, so how to add numbers in mysql statement?

here is what I have so far

```
$sql_data = "UPDATE `database1`.`users` SET (`balance`) = '(what to put here?)'
WHERE ('" . $mysqlid . "') ";
```

so do I have to a) retrieve the current balance with a mysql select query?
and b) what do I use to add the integer 5 to the column balance, the mysql row is double(16,2)

Comment: I feel like I should remind all of you to watch out for SQL injections, maybe by using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$bal=100.5;  // balance to be add
$sql_data = "UPDATE `database1`.`users` SET `balance` = (`balance`+'$bal')  WHERE ('" . $mysqlid . "') ";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql_data = "UPDATE `database1`.`users` SET `balance` = MIN(`balance` + 5, (maximum_value_they_can_have)) WHERE ('" . $mysqlid . "') ";
```

Edit:

Arguably you can do a check to verify that `balance + 5` doesn't go over the bounds of the `balance` data-type in PHP using something that is unlikely to run into issues, like bcmath functions. (Does math via given precision with string comparison)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$sql_data = "UPDATE `database1`.`users` SET `balance` = (`balance` + [value to be added]) WHERE ('" . $mysqlid . "') ";
```